# i cant pass my array into my function

Tags: c++

i am doing a shell sort program but there's some problem passing the array into my function, i have searched for some post about passing array into the function but i still don't understand.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int shellsort(int arr[]){
    int gap = floor(sizeof(arr)/2);
    for(int gap = floor(sizeof(arr)/2); gap < 0; gap=gap/2){
        for(int i = gap; i < sizeof(arr); i++){
            if(arr[i] < arr[i-gap]){
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i-gap];
                arr[i-gap] = temp;
                if(gap == 1){
                    if(arr[i-1] < arr[i-2]){
                        int temp = arr[i-1];
                        arr[i-1] = arr[i-2];
                        arr[i-2] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}


int main(){ 
    int numcount;
    cin>>numcount;
    int numbers[numcount];
    for(int i; i<numcount; i++){
        cin>>numbers[i];
    }   

    int numbers = shellsort(numbers);
    cout<<numbers;
}
```

Comment: You're doing at least 3 things you shouldn't.

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: If you don't want to use a `std::vector`, which you should, make `int shellsort(int arr[])` take the array size `int shellsort(int arr, size_t size)` and read about pointer decay

Comment: `int numbers[numcount];` - You compile with GCC? I suggest you add the `-pedantic` flag and start heeding those warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of what you have promised to return and what you have returned.

```
int shellsort(int arr[]){
    //....
    return arr;//<--- ****not an int****
}
```

Now, either change to use a vector:

```
std::vector<int> shellsort(std::vector<int> arr){
    int gap = floor(arr.size()/2);
    for(int gap = floor(arr.size()/2); gap < 0; gap=gap/2){
        //as above
    }
    return arr;
}
```

or send in the size

```
int * shellsort(int * arr, size_t size){
    int gap = floor(size/2);
    for(int gap = floor(size/2); gap < 0; gap=gap/2){
        //as above
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that inside your function, the actual size of `int arr[]` is not known, and `arr` decays to a pointer, hence `sizeof(arr) == sizeof(int*)`.

I suggest you rewrite your code to use `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

std::vector<int> shellsort(std::vector<int> arr){
    int gap = floor(arr.size()/2);
    for(int gap = floor(arr.size()/2); gap < 0; gap=gap/2){
        for(int i = gap; i < arr.size(); i++){
            // ...as before...
        }
    }
    return arr;
}


int main(){ 
    int numcount;
    cin>>numcount;
    std::vector<int> numbers(numcount);
    for(int i; i<numcount; i++){
        cin>>numbers[i];
    }   

    numbers = shellsort(numbers);
    for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
        cout<<numbers[i];
}
```